# in Godot the optionbutton keeps resizing itself based on the length of the biggest entry. How do I force the control to stay at a fixed size?

Tags: user-interface, game-engine, godot, gdscript

I am feeding database entries into an optionbutton.  If there is an entry bigger than the default size, the control will resize itself based on the length of the biggest entry.  How do I force the control to stay at a fixed size?  Under Rect there are min size entries, the size flag entries seem to have no effect, clip content doesn't help.  Even tried to set the size in code after they were loaded:  `shell_selection_option_button.set_size(Vector2(160,22))`  ...no go.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!   Answering my own question.  Not sure why i didn't see this before, but in the Inspector under 'Button', there is a 'Clip Text' option that does this.

Comment: You can accept your own answer.